# X86 LLVM register bit access by an instruction

Tags: x86, llvm

Is there a way to determine which bits of a register were accessed by a given instruction? I'm trying to write a Function pass that for each usage of the register EAX for example, determines if the same bits were accessed. I've looked into the methods of the MachineInstr, Register, MachineOperand classes but couldn't find any useful information. Is this even possible?

Comment: Not sure if I completely understand this, but this would have to be dealt per case (i.e. per instruction), depending on which [registers](https://llvm.org/docs/MIRLangRef.html#mir-registers) are their operands. More info would help, e.g. a minimal example or current implementation.